# Error when trying to run packaged Jar (Maven)

Tags: maven, jar, jsch

I am having an issue running a JAR that I have packaged using Maven. It is a very simple class that just takes a file from a directory on the local machine and posts it to an SFTP.

I am using the "mvn package" command and am seeing the JAR show up in my target folder, but when I attempt to run the JAR I am getting the following error:

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jcraft/jsch/Jsch
  at. java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0
  etc.

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jcraft.jsch.Jsch"

Now the program runs just fine when I run it in eclipse just running the main method, so I assume that it is something with the maven package command not bringing all the correct classes into my JAR? In my "Maven Dependencies" all I have is the "jsch-0.1.49.jar" and "junit-3.8.1.jar" Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am sure there is a step I missed somewhere in this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maven package command and the maven-jar-plugin did not build jar files with the dependencies attached. They just build a jar file with your project sources.

You need an uber jar which consist of everything your main class need. The easiest way to archive this is by using the [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html):

```
<project>
   ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: Awesome answer, gained understanding of maven, worked perfectly. Couldn't have asked for anything better. Thank you.